# Combine object key values into single string with separator

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve this:

```
var keys = ['name', 'description']

var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolores',
  moreKeysHere: 'moreValues'
}

console.log(obsKeysToString(obj, keys, '-'))
```

Result: `Test - Lorem ipsum dolores`

I have some solution with `for` loop, and some stirring operations and so on but I am sure there's a better way..

Comment: That will join all of the keys, I think the OP wants to join only the keys specified in the array

Comment: @danwellman correct

Comment: @Daniel_L - Length does not determine whether it's an answer or a comment. Even if it's 1 character, if it's an answer to the question then it should be posted as an answer to the question.

Comment: You should post the solutions that you come up with in your questions. It helps to clarify your question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method along with **[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** method. Where **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method can be used for filtering non-empty and defined property values.

```
function obsKeysToString(o, k, sep) {
 // iterate over key array
 return k.map(function(key) {
    // get object property value 
    return o[key];
    // filter out non-empty and defined property
  }).filter(function(v) {
    return v;
    // join the property value array with the separator
  }).join(sep);
}
```

```js
var keys = ['name', 'description']

var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolores',
  moreKeysHere: 'moreValues'
}

function obsKeysToString(o, k, sep) {
  return k.map(function(key) {
    return o[key];
  }).filter(function(v) {
    return v;
  }).join(sep);
}

console.log(obsKeysToString(obj, keys, '-'))
```

---

Same solution with ES6 arrow function

```
function obsKeysToString(o, k, sep) {
 return k.map(key => o[key]).filter(v => v).join(sep);
}
```

```js
var keys = ['name', 'description']

var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolores',
  moreKeysHere: 'moreValues'
}

function obsKeysToString(o, k, sep) {
  return k.map(key => o[key]).filter(v => v).join(sep);
}
console.log(obsKeysToString(obj, keys, '-'))
```

---

Another solution using **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** method.

```
function obsKeysToString(o, k, sep) {
  // iterate over key array
  return k.reduce(function(str, key) {
    // generate string based on each key
    return str + (o.hasOwnProperty(key) ? (str.length ? sep : '') + o[key] : '');
  }, '')
}
```

```js
var keys = ['name', 'description']

var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolores',
  moreKeysHere: 'moreValues'
}

function obsKeysToString(o, k, sep) {
  return k.reduce(function(str, key) {
    return str + (o.hasOwnProperty(key) ? (str.length ? sep : '') + o[key] : '');
  }, '')
}

console.log(obsKeysToString(obj, keys, '-'))
```

Comment: Almost perfect but with same glitch like answer above. If you add a key that does not exist in object, for example ['name', 'description', 'unexisting'] you will end up with `Test - Lorem ipsum dolores -` Unneeded separator at the end.

Comment: @PrimozRome   filter can be use

Comment: what if you don't know the keys ahead of time?

Answer (score 17):

Another answer to show 1-liners for joining `keys`, or `values`, or `both`:

---

**Join Keys: `Object.keys(obj)`**

```js
const obj = {a: '1', b: '2'};
console.log(Object.keys(obj).join(','));
```

---

**Join Values: `Object.values(obj)`**

```js
const obj = {a: '1', b: '2'};
console.log(Object.values(obj).join(','));
```

---

**Join Both: `Object.entries(obj)`**

```js
const obj = {a: '1', b: '2'};
console.log(Object.entries(obj).join(','));
```

Note: `Object.entries(obj)` was announced a standard by ecma in June 2017 ([See link](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object.entries)). Browser support: all except IE Desktop and Mobile Safari.

[image]

**Update**:  `Object.entries(obj)` now supports in Mobile Safari Also

Ref: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```js
 
var keys = ['name', 'description', 'nonExistentProperty']

var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolores',
  moreKeysHere: 'moreValues'
};

// ES6 
console.log(keys.filter(key => typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined').map(key => obj[key]).join(','));

// NON ES6 
console.log(keys.filter(function(key) { return typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined'}).map(function(key) { return obj[key]}).join(','));
```

Comment: Almost perfect, except if you add a key that does not exist in object, for example `['name', 'description', 'unexisting']` you will end up with `Test - Lorem ipsum dolores - ` ... Unneeded separator at the end.

Comment: @PrimozRome yes, i was assuming that the program would know about the keys that were being queried. I edited the question to avoid this case that you brought.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with one line of code...

```js
var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolores',
  moreKeysHere: 'moreValues'
};

console.log(Object.keys(obj).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.reduce` :

```js
const keys = ['name', 'description']

const obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolores',
  moreKeysHere: 'moreValues'
}

console.log(
  keys.reduce(
    function(strs, key) {
      if (obj[key]) strs.push(obj[key]);
      return strs
    }, []).join(' - ')
);
```